# How to translate internal BQ column userid (INTEGER) to e-mail

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm extracting data from Scheduled Queries using this command
`bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=us --format=csv`
One column in the result is called userid (data type INTEGER) and it's a column referring to the user, who created the scheduled query. Hence quite important information.
I'd like to transform this information to a more readable format = an e-mail address. But I haven't been able to find out how.

PS I wonder why this internal value is used here. In other BigQuery system data user names are always presented in readable e-mail format. (Maybe it's because Scheduled Queries is still in beta version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userID` has been deprecated according to [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs)

Please don't rely on that field. There is no other field in place right now. AFAIK only from auditlogs you can obtain these informations.